# Submit a ASPX form with curl from php

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

The form can be fount here: https://services.smartree.com/mcdonalds/applicationform/WebForms/ApplyToJob.aspx

After I get `__VIEWSTATE` & `__EVENTVALIDATION` I start the submit process.

```
// Start Submit process

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);


// Populate all POST fields

$postfields = array();
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = urlencode($eventValidation);
$postfields['__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'] = urlencode('');
$postfields['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = urlencode($eventGenerator);
$postfields['ucApplyToJob$cmbSelectedJob']=urlencode($values['job_type']);
$postfields['ucApplyToJob$txtLastName'] = $values['lname'];
$postfields['ucApplyToJob$txtFirstName'] = $values['name'];  

$p = "";
foreach ($postfields as $k => $v) {
    $p .= $k . '=' . $v . '&';
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch); // Get result after login page.
$err = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$header['errno'] = $err;
$header['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $ret;
print_r($header);
```

I have populated all required fields but nothing. Please help.

Comment: aspx/webform pages have mechanisms in place to try and block remote scripting. This is likely part of your problem. What exactly is happening? Are you getting any errors

Comment: I do not get any error. The response is the html page without any errors or successful messages.